# Private Method in Module Pattern: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, module-pattern, private-methods

I am trying to implement a classic Module Pattern in javascript, discussed [here](http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/) and [here](http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/).  But my private methods are not working.  I have the following bit of testing code.

```
var jsStuff = (function() {

    // Private
    var sayStuffPrivate = function ( stuff ) {
        console.log( "I am a private method: " +  stuff );
        return true;
    };

    // Public
    return {
        sayStuff: function ( stuff ) {
            console.log( "I am a public method: " + stuff );
            this.sayStuffPrivate( stuff );
            return true;
        }
    }
}());
```

When I try to run this, I get the following:

```
> jsStuff.sayStuff('blah');
test.js:16 I am a public method: blah
test.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's not a method, as that would mean it's no more private. It's just a local function, and should be accessed as such; not via `this.` like a public property of your object.

Comment: Note that the value of *this* within a function is determined entirely by how you call the function (or by using *bind*), not lexically (or how the function was created).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.sayStuffPrivate( stuff );
```

Here, `this` refers to the object you actually returned from the `sayStuff` function. That doesn't have a property called `sayStuffPrivate` in it. So, `this.sayStuffPrivate` will be evaluated to `undefined` and since you are using that as a function, it fails with that error.

You are supposed to take advantage of the closure property and invoke it like this

```
sayStuffPrivate( stuff );
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'm new to js, and it seems such a subtle thing.  Obvious, I guess, once you've seen it a few times.

Comment: Incidentally, can private methods call the public ones?  If so, how?

Comment: This answered my second question (Can private methods call the public ones?): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505073/how-can-i-call-a-public-method-from-within-a-private-one-when-using-the-javascri?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You should call sayStuffPrivate without this. Try This:

```
var jsStuff = (function() {

    // Private
    var sayStuffPrivate = function ( stuff ) {
        console.log( "I am a private method: " +  stuff );
        return true;
    };

    // Public
    return {
        sayStuff: function ( stuff ) {
            console.log( "I am a public method: " + stuff );
            sayStuffPrivate( stuff );
            return true;
        }
    }
}());
```